# How would an administrator of a system prevent himself access to a file for 24 hours?

Tags: linux, bash, files, permissions

How would a single administrator go about locking himself out of a file for 24 hours?

By "lock" I mean prevent access.

I have removed the 'rules' placed on the original post, as it is clear that the strategies are dependent on what is being locked.

Comment: @drewbenn the question posed about /etc/hosts should perhaps be asked alone. I am adding a rule that reflects your concern.

Comment: What's the point of these "rules" if you explicitly also want ideas that break them? What exactly does "locking out" mean? That the admin can't read the file? Can't see it? Execute it? Modify it? All of the above? What OS would this be on? Linux only? What does "Root access has to be maintained" mean? What is the actual objective here?

Comment: @terdon I don't think the question as it stands is possible, but asking and impossible question gets no answers at all. A lock prevents access. That is what I mean by 'locked out.' I agree that the third rule is vague. It is now changed.

Comment: OK, so the file can remain visible but its contents can't be read and it can't be modified in any way, right?

Comment: @terdon Yes the file can remain visible. The file can be modified as long as it is restored to its original state.

Comment: I meant while it is "locked". Is it OK if the admin can still move/copy the file as long as they can't read the contents or does the file itself need to be protected from any action the admin takes? Please [edit] your question and make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I think, if possible, it would have to involve encryption - nothing is denied to root (not memory access, not any disk access at any level, not access to mess with the clock to make it look like time has passed when it hasn't).

If the data is on the disk, in a file, already, then an administrator can access that.

Solution 1: Easiest/most reliable solution:
Encrypt the file, put the key/password on a server on the internet that will not release it until the given time.

Solution 2: a kernel module can hide a file; it would also need to block access to memory, disk, and the administrator must also be blocked from physical access (to stop them rebooting into a thumb drive).

Solution 3: taking the way you worded it literally:
Overwrite the data. The administrator will not have access to it in the next 24 hours (nor any time after that, for that matter). Does not move or rename it

Comment: So lets suppose the file is /etc/hosts, if I hide it from the administrator using a kernel module, will it hide it from the system?

Comment: root can restore the kernel module; so that does not completely block root either if he know where to look.

Comment: @Geoff_Clapp  see point 2. "The file is not an executable or system critical."

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "the system".  "the system" consists (roughly) of the kernel (including modules), and processes. A kernel module has information about the process requesting the information, so it could be blocked from (a process called) `cat` but not (a process called) `firefox` - but cannot tell why `firefox` wants the file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Measure the computational power of the computer
2. Calculate the asymmetric encryption key length that's needed such that the computer would be able to brute force the key in more or less 24 hours
3. Find a way to find a number that satisfies the property of a public key without knowing the private key (or more weakly, generate a key pair then throw away the private part)
4. Encrypt the file you want to hide with the public key
5. Start brute forcing the file

You can also use asymmetric encryption here, but that requires you to know the encryption key when you lock yourself out. With asymmetric encryption, you can prepare the public key ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Confine their root account using SELinux (e.g. `semanage user ...`) and install a policy that forbids access to the file for the assigned SELinux user.  Then via cron unconfine their account back.  No encryption, easy, they will have their root account, yet won't be able to do anything with the file.